# Angular Bootstrap 3 nav-bar submenu will not fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have Angular 1.2.1 and  Bootstrap 3.0.2

Plain vanilla nav menu with a drop down works fine but when I try to generate my menu using ng-repeat the submenu will not fire.

The HTML:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="data in main_menu">
                <li ng-class="{'dropdown' : data.nodes}">
                  <a href="{{data.link}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle' : data.nodes}">{{data.name}} <b class="caret" ng-if="data.nodes"></b>
                  <ul ng-if="data.nodes" ng-repeat="items in data.nodes" class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="{{items.link}}">{{items.name}}</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

In the Controller:

```
$scope.main_menu = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    class: '',
    link: '/',
    nodes: false
  },
  {
    name: "DropDown",
    class: 'dropdown-toggle',
    link: '#',
    nodes: [
      {
        name: "Node2",
        class: '',
        link: 'link'
      },
      {
        name: "Node2",
        class: '',
        link: 'link'
      },
      {
         name: "Node2",
         class: '',
         link: 'link'
      },
      {
         name: "Node2",
         class: '',
         link: 'link'
      }
    ]
  }

 ];
```

The normal bootstrap html submenu function works fine .. 
Any suggestion ?

After checking ..

The Angular html Block is not correct, with this adjustment it renders the correct html - the drop down still does not work

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <li ng-repeat="data in main_menu" ng-class="{'dropdown' : data.nodes}">
                  <a href="{{data.link}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle' : data.nodes}">{{data.name}} <b class="caret" ng-if="data.nodes"></b></a>
                  <ul ng-if="data.nodes"  class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li ng-repeat="items in data.nodes"><a href="{{items.link}}">{{items.name}}</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Is this just example code, or is `nodes: false` preventing the dropdown menu from rendering because of the `ng-if="data.nodes"` in the ul?

Comment: This is the actual code .. I do think I have a logic error though .. the ul is rendered

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Add attr `data-toggle="dropdown"` for link.
2. Update controller, change `link: '#'` to `link: ''`.